# PHP: If statements unintentionally causing multiple MySQL columns to update?

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

I have a form on a page containing:

- a text entry box named teachername
- a text entry box named day (in the format YYYY-MM-DD)
- a selection box named "resource" with the options [Library 1 or Library 2]
- a selection box with the values [1,2,3 and 4] named block.

My mysql database has the fields: 
- Teacher

- Library1block1
- Library1block2
- Library1block3
- etc.

The data from the html page is passed onto a php page meant to match the resource and block with the correct mysql field, and update the field so that the data from the text entry box "teachername" is inserted into it.

```
if ($_POST['resource']="Library 1" and $_POST['block']="1")
    {mysql_query(
    "UPDATE Resources
    SET Teacher='yes', Library1block1='$_POST[teachername]'
    WHERE Date='$_POST[day]'");}
if ($_POST['resource']="Library 1" and $_POST['block']="2")
    {mysql_query(
    "UPDATE Resources
    SET Teacher='yes', Library1block2='$_POST[teachername]'
    WHERE Date='$_POST[day]'");}
```

Expected:
- Enter "Mr. Smith" into teachername text entry field, select "Library 1" and "1" within the selection menu, and enter "2012-03-16" in the text entry field named day

- Data is stored and passed along to the php script
- an if statement updates the database record containing the field matched by the "resource"
  field and "block" field (library1b1, library1b2, etc) for the date entered in the day text field
- the field is updated, and the subsequent if statements check to match up the entered data with the correct mysql field

Result:
All fields (not just the specified field) are updated according to the first if statement.

EX: Entering in "Mr. Smith" for teachername, selecting "Library 1", selecting "1" for the block, and entering "2012-03-16" for the date does not update only the Library1block1 field, but it also updates the Library1block2 and library2block1 fields.

The mysql statement, when entered directly into a mysql terminal, updates the singular field correctly, but the usage of this php code results in multiple updated rows.

Help please?

Comment: `a=b` is assignment, `a == b` is check for equality.

Comment: Side point: when outputting an array within double quotes, you have to "escape" it, like so `Library1block1='{$_POST[teachername]}'`

Comment: Second side point, its a bad practice to not put quotes around your array indices: `$_POST['teachername']`

Comment: Also, don't forget there's plenty of changes for SQL injection in that code

Answer (score 3):

You are making a common mistake of using the assignment operator (=) rather than the equality operator (==). On lines that look like this:

```
if($_POST['resource']="Library 1")
```

Change them to use the comparison operator:

```
if($_POST['resource'] == "Library 1")
```

Answer (score 2):

The folks who have given answers have done a good job, but I would like to add one little trick that I like to use sometimes (depending on the language, etc.)

Usually you will write an if statement as something like

```
if ( $var == 1 ) { do_stuff( $var ) }; //or whatever
```

This following simple little trick has made this potential mistake almost impossible for me to make (esp. with php).

***Just switch the two around.***

*So instead of the usual:*

```
if ( $var == 1 ) { do_stuff( $var ) }; //or whatever
```

***Try this instead whenever you can:***

```
if ( 1 == $var ) { do_stuff( $var ) }; //or whatever
```

I'm pretty sure php 5.2+ hasn't changed to the point that it no longer works, but even if you make the mortal mistake of using a single equals sign it should still work because you can't assign a value to a constant (numbers are constant values, right?).

I believe this relies on php's behavior of always processing code from left to right:

```
if ( 1 = $var ) { do_stuff( $var ) }; //or whatever
```

And you're golden! Since I started doing this over 5 years ago I have never run into this problem again. 1 is always 1, no matter what you do. This is a good way of thinking through your conditionals, loops, etc. in php.

The beauty of this is in its mind smacking simplicity. "$var" can be lots of things, but the number 1 is always the number 1. I'm sure this doesn't work for all languages, but for php, it's one I use a lot, and it's apparently a good habit anyway to structure your code this way.

Comment: I have seen this before and if you're used to it, it may be a good practise. I prefer the style `$var = 1` and `$var == 1` wheter I'm comparing or assigning. However, +1 for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **two equal signs** like this in you if statements to **compare values**:

```
$_POST['resource']=="Library 1"
```

This will check if `$_POST['resource']` equals (==) `Library 1`

A single equal sign assigns `Library 1` to `$_POST['resource']`

You may check [**Comparison Operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

**Edit:**

You should also use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for user input value such as $_POST:

```
if ($_POST['resource'] == "Library 1" and $_POST['block'] == "2")
{
    mysql_query(
    "UPDATE Resources
    SET
        Teacher='yes',
        Library1block1='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teachername'])."'
    WHERE
        Date='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['day'])."'"
    );
}
```